# Туры по России или туры в Россию?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как правильно писать: "туры по России" или "туры в Россию"?

Answer (score 2):

Да в общем-то ни то, ни другое не запрещено.

В обычной ситуации более уместно "туры по России", мне кажется. 
Особенно для тех, кто и так живет или находится в России.

"Туры в Россию" требует определенного контекста. Во-первых, это извне скорее всего, а во вторых цель такого тура - скорее всего будет приехать, а не посмотреть.

Comment: Автор, в тексте вопроса, во втором варианте пишет именно "Туры в РоссиЮ". Это значит, что именно "извне". Вы абсолютно правы.

Comment: @romandc, я исхожу из презумпции адекватности автора. Если бы он это знал и понимал, то не стал бы спрашивать.

Comment: Предположительно, для автора вопроса русский язык - второй.

Comment: @romandc Я не делаю таких предположений. Впрочем, это Вашу логику никак не проясняет. Если человек спрашивает, значит не знает или не понимает. Это никак от первого-второго языка не зависит.  Если он так спрашивает, значит не связывает "В Россию" с "извне". А раз не свзявывает, значит Вы не можете делать подобных выводов.

Comment: Пардон. Всё может быть. Никак не хотел вступать с вами в полемику. Вроде бы наоборот - похвалил. :) Значит плохо похвалил. Виноват!

Comment: Здравствуйте. Как автор вопроса хочу добавить коммент. 
Разумеется никакого значения не имеет первый или второй язык, согласен с  behemothus.
Вопрос размещён осознанно, поскольку на всех российских туристических сайтах написано в Россию. Что противоречит логике "извне". Убеждён, что "по" - это правильно не зависимо от того тур предлагается за пределами России или в России.
Туры в Россию? Туры по России!
Путешествие в Россию? Путешествие по России!

Comment: Да, @Тигран, тот комментарий несколько спутал ясную мысль ))). На сайтах-то оно может и есть, но Вы же не зря спросили, там-то и может быть ошибка. Повторю. Вы совершенно правы, единственный всегда и безусловно правильный вариант - "по России". "В Россию" - уже требует определенного контекста, лучше его не использовать, если не увер, что именно он тут уместен.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Мы тоже боремся за чистоту русского языка!